# ethernet not connected after power off and on

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet

[image: ethernet not connected]

Each time I start up my computer after power turned off and on, the ethernet cannot be connected automtically and I have to disable and enable it manually. But the ethernet can connect automatically on start up if the power on all the time.

How can the ethernet connected automatically each time regardless of the power turned off and on?

===add

The monitor and computer are plugged into a power trip.
I just click the button on the power trip to power it off.
The router is powered on all the time.

```
Name    [00000007] Realtek PCIe 2.5GbE Family Controller    
Adapter Type    Ethernet 802.3  
Product Type    Realtek PCIe 2.5GbE Family Controller   
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8125&SUBSYS_87D71043&REV_04\6&102E3ADF&0&0048020A  
Last Reset  7/12/2023 3:16 PM   
Index   7   
Service Name    rtcx21  
IP Address  192.168.1.107   
IP Subnet   255.255.255.0   
Default IP Gateway  192.168.1.1 
DHCP Enabled    Yes 
DHCP Server 192.168.1.1 
DHCP Lease Expires  7/15/2023 1:07 PM   
DHCP Lease Obtained 7/15/2023 11:07 AM  
MAC Address ‪24:4B:FE:45:78:41‬ 
Memory Address  0xFC500000-0xFC6FFFFF   
Memory Address  0xFC510000-0xFC513FFF   
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967266  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967265  
...
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERSTORE\FILEREPOSITORY\RTCX21X64.INF_AMD64_516E5C9B75C49DC2\RTCX21X64.SYS (1.0.0.14, 527.00 KB (539,648 bytes), 5/7/2022 6:24 PM)
```

Comment: What is the OS? How exactly do you power it off? What is the network interface? What is the driver? Please [edit] and post this information as text, [pictures are not enough](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: Try reinstalling the network device’s driver.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski
I added more info to the original post. Can you help take a look? Thank you.

Comment: @eventHandler
I have already reinstalled the network device's driver but it didn't help.